# function(msg) - Search inside

Tags: jquery

I want to check the content of msg after requesting. If there is a specific word inside - the output should another one as the normal one. My "noob" try doesn´t work. Thanks for an idea.

```
data: $(this).serialize(), 
success: function(msg) {
    if (this.value =~ "hello") { 
        $('#output_error').html(msg);
    } 
    else 
        $('#output').html(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to find an occurrence of one string inside another:

```
data: $(this).serialize(), 
success: function(msg) {
    if (msg.indexOf("hello") != -1) { 
        $('#output_error').html(msg);
    } else {
        $('#output').html(msg);
    }
}
```

Further reading on [indexOf at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).